# Get the sum of the same attribute from differently named xml nodes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, xpathdocument

I have an xml file as such

```
<root>
<segmentNameA attributeName="10" />
<segmentNameB attributeName="50" />
</root>
```

Here's my code:

```
XPathDocument xPathDocument = new XPathDocument(analysisFileToProcess);
XPathNavigator  Navigator = xPathDocument.CreateNavigator();
```

I would like to get the sum of all the attributeName attributes (10 + 50).

Here's what I do

```
var sum /*want to obtain 60*/ = Navigator.Select(Navigator.Compile("sum(/root/*[self::segmentNameA or self::segmentNameB]/@attributeName)"));
```

I get an expression "has an invalid token".

However, when I do this

```
var nodes = Navigator.Select(Navigator.Compile("/root/*[self::segmentNameA or self::segmentNameB]"));
```

I get all the nodes which contain the attribute I'd like to sum on.

And when I do that

```
var nodes = Navigator.Select(Navigator.Compile("/root/*[self::segmentNameA or self::segmentNameB]/@attributeName"));
```

I get the list of the attributes. Why can't I use the sum function on this?

Could someone please point out to me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens, because XPath expression must evaluate to a node-set.
Use `Evaluate` method instead:

```
var sum = (double)Navigator.Evaluate("sum(/root/*[self::segmentNameA or self::segmentNameB]/@attributeName)");
```

Comment: Indeed, edited, thanks for the pointer (still does not work though).

Comment: Kirill, now that I think of it, I received this error message, and even though it's pretty straight forward, I did not think of using other methods on my Navigator...it now works like a charm. Thanks a lot.